# subprocess "echo $ENVIRONMENT_VAR" outputs "$ENVIRONMENT_VAR"

Tags: python, bash

Writing a python program running in a linux environment. 
I cannot use paramiko etc in this environment.

I have written a series of methods to interact with the command line the one with the issue...

```
import subprocess

def echo(self, echo_arg):
  cmd = subprocess.Popen(["echo", echo_arg], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  return cmd.communicate()[0]
```

In linux I have an envionment variable UPFW_WORK_PATH
when I later call...

```
self.echo("$UPFW_WORK_PATH")
```

the console output returned is literally :

> $UPFW_WORK_PATH

however when I type into the terminal...

```
echo $UPFW_WORK_PATH
```

I am returned (not actual path names):

> /example/file/path

What is causing this discrepancy between manually typing "echo" to the terminal and my python method calling echo by subprocess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run `echo $x` from the shell, it is the shell that expands the variable into its value. So if the value of x is 5, for example, the argument that `echo` receives is 5. It will never know about the variable.

So the solution is to retrieve the value of the environment variable in your python program and pass that value to echo:

```
import subprocess
import os
echo_arg = os.environ['UPFW_WORK_PATH']
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["echo", echo_arg], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Another solution would be to use `os.path.expandvars(echo_arg)`

Comment: Thanks worked first time!